# Spring Boot - are single implementing classes automatically injected

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, configuration

I am relatively new to Spring in general but have read through the Apress *Spring Rest* text and gotten the examples running in Eclipse without problem.

Something that puzzles me in the examples is how objects appear to be automatically injected.
For example in chapter 8 security there is a `QuickPollUserDetailsService` class which implements the spring `UserDetailsService` class.

The text says the following:

> "The SecurityConfig class declares a `userDetailsService` property, which gets injected with a `QuickPollUserDetailsService` instance at runtime."

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecuritypublic class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter 
{        
@Inject
        private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;        
@Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
                auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)                        .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());        
}}
```

Nowhere in any file does it specify `QuickPollUserDetailsService` is to be set.
Is Spring being smart here and noticing that `QuickPollUserDetailsService` is the only implementer of `UserDetailsService` and therefore assuming that it must be injected?
If that is the case what if I had 2 or more implementer's of `UserDetailsService`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Spring Boot will recursively scan the packages and available implementation will be automatically injected. If there is more than one implementation available, startup will fail.

Comment: cheers for that - and I see the @Qualifier annotation which can be used to specify which implementation to use